# No Instance of Template function with unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I was trying to create a hash table using unordered_map but on Visual Studio 2010 got the error

```
IntelliSense: no instance of function template "std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::emplace [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=std::string, _Hasher=std::hash<std::string>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<std::string>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>]" matches the argument list
```

for the following code segment. The above error comes when I am using the emplace call. How to get around this error?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::tr1::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> hashtable;
    std::tr1::unordered_map <int,int> intmap;
    intmap.emplace(10,20);
    hashtable.emplace("www.element14.com","184.51.49.225");
    std::cout << "IP Address : " <<hashtable["www.element14.com"] <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the above works fine if I use insert like `hashtable.insert(std::make_pair("www.newark.com","184.51.50.121"));`

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ 2010 (and 2012 in fact) don't support variadic templates yet, which is how "emplace" should be implemented. In 2012 they worked around this using a bunch of nasty macros, but in 2010 emplace is only implemented for a single argument (and thus pretty much equivalent to insert).